# How to create a bias field image by matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Let defined the bias field creating:

*The degree of intensity inhomogeneity is indicated by the range of values of the bias field in the interval [1 − α,1+ α] with α> 0.For each α (i.e α=0.1), we generated a bias fields with value in [1 − α,1+ α]*

In addition, I add more condition for bias image creation is that the values of bias image are slowly-varying.

I want to create an 2D bias filed from given α value based on the above definition (with and without condition). Could you help me implement it by Matlab?

```
function bias_Image=create_bias_image(nrow,ncol,alpha)
%% Code here
%% nrow and ncol are size of bias_Image 
end
```

Currently, this is what I tried by bellow code. However, I have no idea to said that my code is whether correct or not.

```
function bias_Image=create_bias_image(nrow,ncol,alpha)
%% Code here
%% nrow and ncol are size of bias_Image
bias_Image=zeros(nrow,ncol);
for i=1:nrow
   for j=1:ncol
     %% create a random number in range [1 − alpha,1+ alpha]
     %% Without condition 
     bias_Image(i,j)= (1- alpha) + 2*alpha.*rand(1,1);
     %% With condition slowly varying-how to do it

   end
end
end
```

For easy visualization, I think this is good example image with alpha=0.2
[image]

Comment: How can this field be "slowly varying" if you're throwing random values in the image?  Throwing in random values won't have the appearance that the output is going to look slowly varying.

Comment: @rayryeng: Yes, it is that i am confusing. Actually, I used the definition of slowly varying from http://brainweb.bic.mni.mcgill.ca/faq.html#how-inu-fields

Comment: I don't quite see where the definition is... do you have another reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your defination. We can easily create 1D linear value and combine it in 2D to create your bias image. The good way is

```
x=1:0.01:256;
y=1:0.01:256;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
bias=[X.*Y];
x = bias(:);
alpha=0.5;
up_range=1+alpha;
down_range=1-alpha;
bias_X = (x - min(x)) * (up_range - down_range) / (max(x) - min(x)) + down_range;
bias_scalar=reshape(bias_X,[n m]);
```